# jQuery - can't access to $.get response data

Tags: jquery, json, get, scope

I have this code :

```
function retrieve_districts(){

var json='';

$.get("http://localhost/aaa/districts.php",function(result, textStatus) {       
    if(textStatus=="success"){
        json=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)); (alert works fine here)
    }
}, "json");

alert(json);
```

}

but the alert is empty, how can I do ?  thank you very much

Comment: And what is the problem with having the `alert` in the location where it actually works?

Comment: He's making a call, ***parsing it twice***, gonna find out who's naughty and nice....

Comment: I'm sorry, there was already a similar issue :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639555/jquery-return-get-data-in-a-function

Answer (score 1):

Alerting your json, wont work at the bottom of the code. The json variable is not populated until the Ajax call is completed, hence why the alert works fine inside the if statement.

You can put a callback method inside the if statement and call that back once your Ajax query is completed.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the wonderful world of asynchronous programming!

you have to move the `alert` inside the callback function.

you might push you code to behave like synchronous but, I would not recommend it, you will always find yourself struggling against the design.

Answer (score 0):

The alert is empty because the value of `json` is `''` when you execute the alert.

AJAX is, by design, asynchronous.  So while it's technically *possible* that it may complete before another line of code that follows it (though it's *highly unlikely* in this example), it's not *guaranteed*.  When an AJAX request is launched, it continues in another thread and the rest of the inline code continues immediately without waiting for the AJAX request to complete.

So in order to do anything in response to your AJAX request, you need to do it in the callback function:

```
function retrieve_districts(){

    var json='';

    $.get("http://localhost/aaa/districts.php",function(result, textStatus) {       
        if(textStatus=="success"){
            json=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
            alert(json);
        }
    }, "json");
}
```

That function which gets passed into the `get()` function is the callback and will be executed after the AJAX request completes.