# Dynamicly creating a js array with php every x seconds

Tags: javascript, php

I am populating a js array thanks to php every 2 seconds but it works only the first time because the php code is executed only when I open the window but I want to execute it every time I launch the js function.

Here is my code :

```
function update(){
    var datas = <?php echo Gallery::getPhotos(); ?>;
    ...
}

setInterval( "update()", 2000 );
```

The problem is that the `var datas` never changes because `<?php echo Gallery::getPhotos(); ?>;` is executed only the first time. How can I do to execute the php every 2 seconds ? 
I saw solutions with doing a request on a file but I don't know how to do and I don't know if this is the solution for only 1 instruction.

`Gallery` is a singleton class which stores pictures, the function `getPhotos()` returns an array with photos names.

Comment: [Asynchronous JavaScript + XML (Ajax)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX)

Comment: While I know AJAX can be used to do this, I couldn't find a SO question that asked this, rather than something about AJAX. If someone else can find a duplicate, please flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `<?php ... ?>` is only run on a page load, you may have to use AJAX. Below is a rudimentary example:

**EDIT:** Heres a working example:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.get("myphp.php",function(data){
        update(data);
    });
},5000);

function update(data){
    //...
}
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Thank you I will try this ! So we have to create a file, otherwise, we can't do a request

Comment: Has it been a success?

Comment: Almost, I can get the datas but I can't use them outside of the function

Comment: I find the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1639584/4623982
Unfortunately, your solution doesn't works, it is explained why there

Comment: Fair enough, may I ask which answer you used?

Comment: I choosed the one on the link

Comment: My solution would work, as we don't return the `$.` (XHR) object. After checking my code, I realise it doesn't wait for a response when returning. Anyways, I assume your retrieval now works. Please note that using a **syncronous** task can cause the browser to lock up when waiting for a response, hence I suggested an **asyncronous** answer above. I have added an edit to my answer with a working (and tested) example of an **ansycronous** catered for you :-)